# Custom DataGridViewCell, second click to edit

Tags: winforms, datagridview, cell, editing

I've implemented my own DataGridViewCell with a colour picker / opacity cell.

I want the cell to behave as per the standard controls, such as DataGridViewTextCell which you first click to select, then click again to edit.

The obvious thing was to call BeginEdit from with in the Click handler if Selected is true, but I my cell state is always Selected by the time the click handler is invoke. I can't see how to differentiate the state of the control between the first and second clicks.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by handling MouseDown

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    _nextClickBeginEdit = Selected;
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}

protected override void OnClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
    if (_nextClickBeginEdit)
    {
        DataGridView.BeginEdit(false);
    }
}
```